# Proof of limit of uniformly convergent sequence of continuously differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

I have tried to prove the following theorem by following the proof in my lectures. My question is similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2797613/show-that-f-n-converges-uniformly-to-some-continuously-differentiable-func), but at a lower level (I do not know about Banach spaces). May I ask if my understanding is correct? Thank you.

> **Theorem.** Let $(f_n)_{n∈\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of continuously differentiable functions on $[a, b].$ Assume that
> (i) $(f′_n)_{n∈\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to a function $g : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$;
> (ii) $(f_n(a))_{n∈N}$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$.
> Then $(f_n)_{n∈N}$ converges uniformly to a function $f$ on $[a, b]$ that is continuously differentiable and satisfies $f′ = g$ on $[a, b]$.

By the corollary to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (FTC), we have that $$f_n(x) = f_n(a) + \int_a^x f_n'(t) dt.$$
for each $x ∈ [a, b]$. Note that $g$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, by Weierstrass' theorem. We claim that $f$ is defined by
$$f(x) = L + \int_a^x g(t) dt,$$
for each $x \in [a,b]$ and where $L := \textrm{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(a).$
By the FTC, $\int_a^x g(t) dt$ is differentiable on $[a, b]$ and its derivative is equal to $g$ on $[a,b]$. By the sum rule for derivatives, $f'(x) = 0 + g(x) = g(x)$ for each $x \in [a,b]$.
As g is continuous, f is continuously differentiable. It now remains to show that the convergence is uniform. Note that, by subtracting the above equations and using the linearity of the integral, we obtain:
$$ |f(x) - f_n(x)| = |L - f_n(a) + \int_a^x (g-f'_n)(t) dt|.$$
By the triangle inequality and the continuity of the integral, we obtain:
$$ |f(x) - f_n(x)| \leq |L - f_n(a)|  + ||g-f_n||_{[a,x]}(x-a) \leq |L - f_n(a)|  + ||g-f'_n||_{[a,b]}(b-a).$$
By hypothesis, since $f_n(a) \to L$ and $f' \to g$ uniformly, we obtain that
$$ f_n \to f$$
uniformly on [a,b].

Is there any parts of the proof which are incorrect/can be simplified? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like all the right ideas are in place (didn't check inequalities for you however).  The key (as you note) is that, since $f_n'$ are assumed to be continuous, you can use integrals.  If you drop "continuity" the theorem is still valid but forget using integrals--not even the Lebesgue integral can come to the rescue this time.  But you can still prove by elementary means using the old mean-value theorem of the calculus. See **Theorem 9.37** in this textbook if you need some hints: http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Portrait.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot for the book!